# How to serialize FormData that includes blob images?

Tags: javascript, ajax, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to serialize a javascript FormData that includes a blob image file.

When I try to convert the FormData to a JSON object via Object.fromEntries it loses the blob image.

Does anyone know how to do this without losing the blob image?

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('id','1234');
formData.append('imageFile',data, 'blob');

console.log('FormData');
console.log(formData);

let formObj = Object.fromEntries(formData);

console.log('FormDataObj');
console.log(formObj);

let formSear = JSON.stringify(formObj);

console.log('FormDataObjSear');
console.log(formSear);
```

Here's a running example [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/nyz58j0u/3/)

Comment: `FormData` is generally used when submitting data that can't be done as JSON. Why do you think you need to convert it to JSON?

Comment: @Barmar I have a chrome extension.  I need to send formData from the content scripts to the background page.  All messages to and from background pages need to be serialized.

Comment: Maybe use `URL.createObjectURL(data)` to convert the blob to a URL string?

Comment: @NullReference You should put that info in your question and add the relevant tags

Comment: Use `URL.createObjectURL(await new Response(formObj).blob())` then fetch it in the background script.